# Where can I find records of old FAA registrations?

Tags: faa, aircraft-registration

I know where to find details for [FAA N-Number registrations](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/nnum_inquiry.aspx). But where can I find records and details on older FAA NC, NR, NL, and NX numbers?

Comment: Its entirely possible that they aren't available electronically. Those prefixes were used prior to 1949 and may not have been digitized. You can probably try to request copies of those records through the FAA, but I'm sure it won't be easy, or cheap.

Comment: Resource location is off-topic as defined by the [help center](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

NC, NR, NL or NX are not necessarily older aircraft. Any aircraft more than 30 years old can use NC instead of just N.

So, to find the a/c registration you just take out the C.

I own a glider that was built in 1965 so my numbers are NC and 5 digits.

It should be the same for R, L, and X, which are any aircraft that has a restricted, limited or experimental airworthiness certificate can use those letters after the N. See [FAR Part 45.22](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/CFB016AA41963A1C86256A6900512337?OpenDocument).

Comment: This does not answer my question on where I can find info on these registrations

Comment: The point is that the premise of your question is incorrect. Only NC is for 30 yrs or older aircraft. For all of those registration marks, remove the C, R, L and X and search on that on the FAA web site.