# How to identify an aircraft from its NC- N-number?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I have the numbers from the tail NC and then down is 4686N. Its a single wing prop driven multi seat aircraft. I am unable to locate it on the federal site, hoping I can get some info here again. Thanks, Ron

Comment: What does "tail NC and then down is 4686N" mean exactly? The confusing part is the "then down" part, is the number on two lines? Is it "NC" (next line) "4686N"?

Comment: Are you able to post a picture of it, or a link to a picture? And is it a US aircraft?

Comment: The top of the tail section has NC and just below that 1 number after another 4 then 6 then 8 and so on.

Comment: I'm afraid that attaching a photo seems to be more than I am able to do! It's not just a matter of attaching a photo from my collection. OR is it?

Comment: @Pondlife "NC" is an older FAA registration type. I had a [question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30805/where-can-i-find-records-of-old-faa-registrations) about them before.

Comment: As I understand it ...N means American & C means Civilian. At least I hope so.

Comment: Based on the re-edit, it would be a duplicate of [this](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30805/where-can-i-find-records-of-old-faa-registrations) question.

Comment: You should be able to post a photo from your collection. It will be uploaded to the SE image sewer and linked to so it won't go broken. If you edit your question there should be a camera icon to add an image

Answer (score 5):

Single wing prop driven multi seat aircraft? Not sure what you mean by this. A quick search on the [FAA registry](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=4686N) indicates it's a Cessna 414A.

Also, the style of tail number with NC is older, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_registration) has an explanation of the various styles of aircraft identifications.

> An older aircraft (registered before 31 December 1948) may have a second letter in its identifier, identifying the category of aircraft. This additional letter is not actually part of the aircraft identification (e.g. NC12345 is the same registration as N12345).

An older aircraft with the same N-number on the FAA registry is the [BT-13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vultee_BT-13_Valiant).

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE!

Comment: +1 and welcome, I added a quote as not to be a link-only answer, plus more info from the link you provided.

Comment: Thanks so much for the lead to the BT-13. I will look it up now. Back to your other comment this aircraft not only had the NC12345 but it did have the numbers first and the N designation last. Does that affect it in any way?

Comment: @RonatNuRoadCollectibles The last N is just like a number. The format can be 123AB or 1234A or 12345. Only the letters I and O are not allowed as they can be confused for 1 and 0.

Comment: Thanks to all, it looks like my photos are of a BT-13 as suspected  earlier.

Answer (score 0):

FAA registry entails that in the United States and most of northern america, aircraft are classified and registered into the FAA database via something known as an "N-number" to FAA specialists, and to their website. For every American-made/American registered aircraft, there is a respective N-number for it. For example, there are several different occurances of patterns in the N-number system in North America, you can have a registry with N457FR, where there are two letters on the end of the registry, or you can also have only one letter, and eventually only five numbers and only the "November", of which, five-number registry combinations are not as frequent in the United States, but can be found sometimes in the Caribbean and Canada. It also may be worth stating that the letters at the end of a registry can also be a direct effect of the aircraft's owner, date of purchase, or airline. For example, the regional airline company, Air Wisconsin, a subsidiary of US Airways (now American) have the letters "AW" at the end of each of their aircraft's registry. Furthermore, aircraft that are private and are not owned by any airline cooperation of such may have their aircraft's callsign be its registry. FedEx and most small Private Jet charter services have been well-known for doing this. You can find almost any aircraft registry on flightaware.com or by simply googling the callsign or registry.

Comment: Thank you Eric, it gives me additional areas to search into for other photos that I have.